# How many file descriptors accessing a given file?

Tags: linux, file-descriptors

On linux, is there a way to count the number of file descriptors open to a some file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [lsof command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) will tell you all the open files and what program has them open.

`lsof filename`

Comment: No need for `grep`: `lsof filename`

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
fuser -v filename
```